# How to fix 404 'Resource cannot be found' in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a login page in ASP.NET MVC and i am facing an issue :

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

**Requested URL:**  /Verify

I tired a custom route but it doesn't seem to fix it.
 This is my only controller in here

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    MySqlDataReader dr;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    void connectionString()
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=prodavnica;Uid=root`;Pwd=1234;Port=3306";
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Verify(Account acc)
    {


            connectionString();
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from prodavnica.vraboteni where korisnik='" + acc.Username + "'and lozinka='" + acc.Password + "' ";

            if(dr.Read())
            {
                conn.Close();
                return View("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Close();
                return View();

            }

    }
}
```

}
**Route config:**

```
     routes.MapRoute(

            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Here is the front end of the project and also i have a layout, i tried multiple times but i still get the same error

```
/head>
<body>
<div class="login-form">
    <form action="Verify" method="post">
        <h2>Најави се</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Корисник : </label>
            <input type="text" name="Username" class="form-control" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Лозинка: </label>
            <input type="password" name="Password" class="form-control" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">
                Најави се
            </button>
            <label class="checkbox-inline pull-left remember-me"><input type="checkbox" /> Запамти ме</label>
        </div>
        <div><a href="#">Проблеми со најавувањето ? </a></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

It has a post method.

Comment: The requesting url should have `http://yoursite/Home/Verify` -- not just `http://yoursite/Verify`...which are testing with?

Comment: I tried to change the  ' url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",' to display the Home but still i get the same error

Comment: Yes, i am testing it from my browser. And it displays just : https://localhost:44334/Verify

Comment: Two things affecting your test: 1) the controller action you are testing is a POST action so you cannot test it with your browser (I missed this fact initially) 2) even if the controller action you are trying to test was a GET it still would not work using: `localhost:44334/Verify`  because it must be `localhost:44334/Home/Verify`

Comment: Should i change the route config ?

Comment: I believe that your route config is fine -- default should work and I think that is what you have.  If you are posting you must have a view with the post link rendered at some point...show that source code.

Comment: I have only one controller named HomeController

Comment: I updated the question, this is all of the code

Comment: There is also VIEW code somewhere -- these should be in `.cshtml` files.  Without them you would not see anything.  I assume that you are able to get `localhost:44334/Home/Index` to render -- yes?

Comment: It renders and i have an index and a layout view.

Comment: Now find your view code for `Verify` -- how are you expecting the user to get there in the first place?  Usually the pattern is like this: GET -> actionname; then user sees form, enters data, clicks SAVE (or whatever); this causes POST -> same actionname...It can be arranged differently but this is typical -- does your `Index` view present the user something that POSTs to `Verify` ???

Comment: I uploaded the form

Comment: Try changing this: `<form action="Verify" method="post">` to the following: `<form action="Home/Verify" method="post">` ...which brings us all the way back to my very first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do /Verify or /Home/Verify on that form action, missing that initial slash.

If that doesn't work, Open up developer tools in chrome and on the network tab ensure it's a post request and ensure the parameter is being passed correctly as well to the action. Please post here what you see if in case you need help with that.